# How to create instance of child scriptable object base on string?

Tags: unity, scriptable-object

I am working on an Unity3D project and I have a base scriptable object and several child classes that inherit from this parent class.

```
public class Animal:ScriptableObject{}
public class Cat: Animal{}
public class Dog: Animal{}
```

I have a list of strings containing the name of the animals. I would like to create a correct instance base on a given string.
My current workaround is using a switch statement

```
public Animal CreateAnimalFromString(string animalName)
{
   switch (animalName)
   {
     case "Cat":
         return ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Cat>();
     case "Dog":
         return ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Dog>();
     default:
         return ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Animal>();
   }
}
```

This works fine if I have a small number of child classes, but is there a better way to do this?Thank you!

Comment: The reason why people use ScriptableObjects is so you can treat them like assets and edit their values like assets - via the default inspector, a custom inspector or a custom editor window. When you don't intend to do that, then you probably don't need ScriptableObjects. Plain old C# classes will do the job just as well. (Yes, you can have plain old C# classes in a Unity project).

Comment: @Philipp I am aware that I can treat them like assets. What i am trying to do is that I have a csv file containing all the information of scriptable objects. I am trying to write a custom parser that will parser the file and automatically generate the ScriptableObjects for me. A SciptableObject will allow me to visualize the value in editor and modify them more easily.

Comment: This sounds like a script that is going to run exactly once and then never again. Why overthink this so much?

Comment: @Philipp You are correct, this will only run when I regenerate the objects. However, if I have 20 or 30 child classes, the switch statement will become extremely long. Also, everytime I add a child class, I will also have to append the switch statement. That's why I want to know if there is a more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: Well, I guess you could whip something up via reflection. But the time it takes to write that you could easily write a 30-step switch/case statement as well.

Comment: Yes, but what if I want to replace the function in the switch statement. Do I just write a whole new switch and replace every line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another version of [ScriptableObject.CreateInstance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.CreateInstance.html) that allows you to create instances by `Type`:

> public static ScriptableObject CreateInstance(Type type);

You can use the relevant functions of the `System.Reflection` package to find the `Type` through the type name string:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("Namespace.MyClass, MyAssembly");
```

or

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(SomeTypeInTheSameAssembly).Assembly;
Type type = assembly.GetType("Namespace.MyClass");
```

code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Animal : ScriptableObject { }
    public class Cat : Animal { }
    public class Dog : Animal { }

    public class GameUtil
    {
        public static Animal CreateAnimalFromString(string animalName)
        {
            Assembly assembly = typeof(Animal).Assembly;
            Type type = assembly.GetType($"MyNameSpace.{animalName}");
            return ScriptableObject.CreateInstance(type) as Animal;
        }
    }
}
```

If you modify the design and don't want to rely on `ScriptableObject`(just as suggested), you can also create instances directly through reflection:

```
public static Animal CreateAnimalFromString(string animalName)
{
    Assembly assembly = typeof(Animal).Assembly;
    return assembly.CreateInstance($"MyNameSpace.{animalName}") as Animal;
}
```

In addition, the use of reflection is a low-efficiency approach. Generally speaking, it should be avoided as much as possible. A small switch structure may be more suitable for the current situation than reflection.

As for the problem of subsequent modification that you are worried about in the comments, it may be solved with some paperwork tricks. Here I recommend to you the **multi-line editing** function that most modern IDE software has.

Create:

[image]

Modify:

[image]

Comment: WTF is that multiple editing, how <> get separated animal? HOLY<COW>!